# Spring update value from multiple models elements in Jsp

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, model

In my controller:

```
@Controller
public class RandomController {

@RequestMapping(value="/randomPage", method=RequestMethod.GET){

    Map<String, Map<String, Object>> model = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Object>>();
    List<Builds> builds = new ArrayList<Builds>();
    model.put("buildCommand", builds);

    List<BuildTypes> buildTypes = new ArrayList<BuildTypes>();
    buildTypes = buildTypesBus.findListById(buildCommand.getBuildId() );
    model.put("buildTypes", buildTypes);

    .......bunch of other stuff here

    return new ModelAndView("randomPage", model);
    }

  }
```

Then in my view of randomPage.jsp:

I would have a  for loop through all the buildCommand and display 
buildCommand.name
buildCommand.buildTypeId
etc.

The question I want to know is how do I pull the buildTypes.name from the buildTypes and relate that to buildTypeId.
I know I could crate a loop though the list of buildTypes  till I find the buildTypeId and then pull the name, but I feel this is really inefficient. I could also go through hibernate and change the model but do not want to do this, would rather handle this in the jsp. Is there a faster more efficient alternative.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your code what exactly you're trying to do, and that snippet won't compile (for example, what is `buildCommand` in the `findListById` method?) but I'm guessing that for each `Builds` object in your `List<Builds>` you need to associate a `BuildType`.  If that's the case, you could use a `Map` in your jsp.  For example:

```
Map<Integer, BuildType> buildMap = new HashMap<Integer, BuildType>();
for(Builds build : builds) {
  BuildType type = buildTypesBus.findById(build.getId());
  map.put(build.getId(), type);
}
```

Then, in your view, you could use a `<c:forEach items="${builds} var="build">` loop and look up each build type in the `buildMap` like so: `${buildMap[build.id]}`.  That would return a `buildType` object and you could access it like anything else in the map, for example `${buildMap[build.id]}.name`.

Again, I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but it sounds like a `Map` is one way to solve your problem.